# React native: google places alternative for places autocomplete

Tags: react-native, google-places-api

I'm trying to build a search bar component with map places autcomplete without using google places api (too expensive), but didn't found any promising alternatives out there! could anyone tell me if there are some alternative solutions for this?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have used `foursquare` instead of  `google-places-api` and it was quiet good . Although it's more complex to use.
[Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/)